# How to create a function pointer for muParser

Tags: c++

I would like to define a new function in muParser [Link](http://muparser.beltoforion.de/). 
The `FunctionWrapper`-Class should be registrated.

```
class FunctionWrapper
{
public:
virtual double Evaluate(const double*, int) = 0;
};
```

The `DefineFun`-Method needs a string and a function pointer. How can I make this pointer to the function `Evaluate`?

I would like to call the `DefineFun` in an other class... something like this:

```
bool OtherClass::RegisterFunction(std::string name, FunctionWrapper *wrapper)
{
   fParser.DefineFun(name, wrapper->????);
}
```

THx

Comment: I get this error: `no matching function for call to ‘mu::ParserCallback::ParserCallback(double (FunctionWrapper::*&)(const double*, int), bool&)’`

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered std::function as your wrapper? In conjunction with std::bind or lambdas, it can probably do everything you need. E.g.,

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <exception>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Evaluator
{
public:
    virtual ~Evaluator() {}
    virtual double Evaluate( const double*, int ) = 0;
    // ...
};

class Registry
{
public:
    typedef std::function<double(const double*, int)> Fn; // For easier reading

    class NameNotFoundException : public std::exception {};

    void Register( const std::string& name, const Fn& fn )
    {
        _regMap[ name ] = fn;
    }

    void Call( const std::string& name, const double* const data, const int size )
    {
        auto it = _regMap.find( name );
        if( it == _regMap.end() )
        {
            throw NameNotFoundException();
        }

        it->second( data, size ); // Call fn
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, Fn> _regMap;
};

class EvaluatorImpl : public Evaluator
{
public:
    double Evaluate( const double* const data, const int size ) 
    { /*...*/
        for( int n=0; n < size; ++n )
            std::cout << data[n] << '\n';
        return 0;     
    }
    // ...
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Evaluator> eval( new EvaluatorImpl() );

    Registry reg;

    // Could use a lambda here instead of std::bind
    reg.Register( "Bob", 
        std::bind( &Evaluator::Evaluate, eval, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2 ) );

    const double data[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int size = 3;

    reg.Call( "Bob", data, size );
}
```

Comment: I get an error: `invalid use of non-static member function ‘double FunctionWrapper::Evaluate(const double*, int)’` when I call `std::bind` and the muParser can't handle the parameter `std::function`

Comment: Ok, if this (corrected) code will not work, can you please provide the specific muParser function that you're trying to use? If you're trying to use a member function pointer, it either needs to be a static member or you need to supply an instance for it to be called on.

Comment: I poked around the mu site. You need to provide more code. Post a complete *but minimal* sample that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

here a sample Code:

```
#include <functional>
#include "muParser.h"

class Evaluator
{
public:
   virtual ~Evaluator() {}
   virtual double Evaluate( const double*, int ) = 0;
   // ...

   typedef std::function<double(const double*, int)> Fn; // For easier reading
};


class EvaluatorImpl : public Evaluator
{
public:
   double Evaluate( const double* const data, const int size )
   {  return 0; }

};

void MyClass::test()
{
    Evaluator *e = new EvaluatorImpl();
    Evaluator::Fn fn = std::bind( &Evaluator::Evaluate, e, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2 );

   mu::Parser fParser;
   fParser.DefineFun("test", fn);
}
```

I get `no matching function for call to mu::ParserCallback::ParserCallback(std::function<double(const double*, int)>&, bool&)’` when I call `DefineFun(string, T a_func)`